# Get bot to edit old message by id

Tags: discord.py

How do i get my discord.py bot to edit an old message by id? i have this:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("role1", "role2")
async def rulesedit(message: messageid):

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(162, 28, 29))

    embed.add_field("yes")

    await message.message.edit(embed=embed)
```

but i get this error despite it being a message the bot has previously already sent:

```py
Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50005): Cannot edit a message authored by another user
```

Comment: The error literally tells you what went wrong? The bot can only edit its own message(s)...

Comment: the id is an id of a message that the bot has sent already through an earlier command.

Comment: i feel like i'm not actually telling the bot to edit the specific ID i'm giving and it's trying to edit the command i'm sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few logic errors in your code, so it can't work that way at all.

**Point 1:**
A `field` in an embed always needs a `value` and a `name`, otherwise you get an error.

**Point 2:**
You have to query the message via `fetch`, but beware: This is an API query and should not be used too often.

**Here is a working code:**

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_any_role("role1", "role2")
async def rulesedit(ctx, messageid):
    try:
        msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(messageid) # Fetch the ID, needs to be executed in the wanted channel
        embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.green()) # Changed the Color

        embed.add_field(name="TEST", value="TEST") # Added a correct field

        await msg.edit(content = None, embed=embed) # Removed the old content/message and replaced it with the embed
    except:
        return
```

Of course I changed and omitted some things, you would have to add/change them again if needed.

Comment: thank you, i feel like an idiot. the embed.add_field was intentionally wrong (i should have specified that) i didn't even think to fetch the message id so i feel stupid lol

Comment: @ConnorHancock No problem. If this helped you make sure to accept the answer. Happy coding!

Comment: yeah worked perfect thank you, added the ability to send the changelog into a separate channel for us admins to be noted about to, so it's all great. THank you!